# how to make a responsive dialog box in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I Got a situation here,Am new to angular and trying to work out with angular dialog box but the problem is i want to make it as responsive but its not happening and totally messing up with that view of the page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip79Z.png)

This is normal dialog box view in laptop but when it comes to mobile its messing up as follow[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blolt.png)

and my html code for that is

`
    Add Employee
    
    clear

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="300px" layout-gt-sm="column" layout-sm="row">
    <mat-grid-tile layout-sm="column" flex-sm="100">
        <div class="controles-container" layout-sm="column" flex-sm="100">

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Employee No</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="employeeNo" formControlName="employeeNo">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="name" formControlName="name">

            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Design</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="design" formControlName="design">


            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile layout-sm="column" flex-sm="100">
        <div class="controles-container" layout-sm="column" flex-sm="100">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="age" formControlName="age">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Phone</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="phone" formControlName="phone">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>E-mail</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="email" formControlName="email">
            </mat-form-field>


            <nav id="Buttons">

                <button class="ilogin" mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLinkActive="active" type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Save</button>
                <button id="Cancel" mat-raised-button color="" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="onClose()">Cancel</button>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to make the dialog responsive. You need to make the content responsive.

First you need to decide what you want to happen.  Two ways around it.

1. Take the right side and put it below the three items of the left side
2. Take the first of the left, then below it the first if the right and so forth.

The solution for that would be to use the bootstrap `col` classes

Check bootstrap grid system https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ for examples.

If you go for the second option,  you need to change the html to make rows instead of going with two columns.

Comment: that bootstrap worked for me.. Thank you for that clarification..

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/ccept answers that are helpful to you